# Producing multiple map PDF from Excel file with each record being two lat/long pairs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, pdf

I need to produce multiple maps from a single excel file consisting of approximately 1,500 records.  Each record contain two lat/long pairs (four points) and I need a PDF map of each record zoomed to the extents of the four points.  Can this be done using data driven pages or through the ArcPy mapping python object?  Thanks to all.

The records are part of a task related to public transport planning.  Four points, four lat/long pairs.  The four points are "pairs" (origin/destination and boarding/alighting). I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.  Please forgive any confusion.

Comment: Two lat-long pairs would be two points, not four?

Comment: @Simbamangu two lat/long pairs can define opposite corners of a rectangle but you are right that the wording is loose and should be revised

Answer (score 3):

I see the solution to this as being a two step process:

1. Use ArcPy to create a polygon feature class from your lat/long pairs - a technique like this is described in [Automatically create polygons from top right and bottom left coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75987/automatically-create-polygons-from-top-right-and-bottom-left-coordinates)
2. Use the polygon feature class created in step 1 as the index for Data Driven Pages from where exporting to a multi-page PDF is straightforward.

Comment: I like the solution, but what about overlapping polygons?

Comment: @user27907 Overlapping polygons should work just as well in a DDP index as non-overlapping.